# Changing the order of operations inside a while() loop

Tags: python

I'm new to python and am taking a class so far my program looks like:

```
if choice=="1":
    def addition():
        print("You are doing addition. X+Y=Z")
        X = int(input("Enter X:"))
        Y = int(input("Enter Y:"))
        sum = X + Y
        print ("your total is:")
        print (sum)


    Well = "y"
    while Well == "y":
        again = input("Would you like to go again? (y/n)")
        if again == "y":
            addition()
        if again == "n":
            project()
        else:
            print("sorry re-enter choice")
```

it asks if I wan to go again before showing the actual addition part. how do I fix this? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! It will become your best friend if you stick with programming.

Comment: Maybe init well with something other than "y"

Answer (score 2):

Lots of ways, but you could put your `addition()` function at the top like this:

```
Well = "y"
while Well == "y":
    addition()
    again = input("Would you like to go again? (y/n)")
    if again == "n":
        project()
    if again not in ("n", "y"):
        print("sorry re-enter choice")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a flag which changes from `false` to `true` on first run, so that you don't see the "again" statement on first run.

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

- You shouldn't use **`sum`** as a variable name.  It is a Python built in.
- Look at what variable you use for your loop check, you will notice it quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would make more sense to ask if you want to go again at the end of the loop, after you do your stuff:

```
while loop_condition:
    #do_your_stuff:
    bla bla bla

    #see if you should go again
    bla bla = raw_input("Do you want to go again")
```

In fact, 99% of the time your while loops will follow this pattern (check condition, run body of loop, update condition) and if you are doing things in a different order (like iupdating the condition before running the body) its usually a sign you might be doing something wrong.